# Did Pitohui have a special nerve gear?

Tags: sword-art-online, gun-gale-online

In the last few episodes of *Gun Gale Online*, it was shown that Pito was hyperventilating and should have been ejected from the game, but she wasn't.

It was discussed that she could be using a NerveGear, but this was never elaborated on.

Does the manga or other sources mention if Pito actually did have a NerveGear? Or just a modified version of the new one?

Comment: She was using the nerve gear meant for the original Sword Art Online game, the one that has the ability to kill you.

Comment: But then, why didn't she die when she died in game to LLenn?

Comment: Because it didn't have the safety, auto disconnect features of the 2nd gen amusphere, which is basically a modified nervegear with safety features. You can still use a nervegear to connect to full dive games as seen by kirito being able to use it to play ALO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

She was using the original Sword Art Online Nerve Gear, which had the capability to kill you.

The difference with the Nerve Gear and the Amusphere are the safety mechanisms put on the Amusphere to prevent the software from killing you by inducing high voltages into your brain. This is also why Pito didn't get auto ejected when hyperventilating.

Yes, Pito using the Nerve Gear could still kill her, but GGO doesn't have the functionality to fry your brain when you die... (duh) like SAO did

Comment: So was the whole tension of her "actually dying" if LLENN didn't compete just a big Red Herring? Given your answer it leads me to believe that there was no actual risk of death other than possible heart failure due to adrenaline

Comment: Actually, what she said was "if she died she will kill herself" so the risk was that if she died in the game she would scuicide in real life. So no there was no real risk of death except u'kno... she's a bit psychopathic.

Comment: Well looks like I missed that bit. Maybe I just didn't read fast enough. Thanks for clearing up my curiosity

Comment: The reason why she didn't kill herself when llenn killed her was they made a promise to meet up IRL if llenn beat her. And then she could have a chance to convince her otherwise when they do meet.